# How do I add pictures to clickcounter text display? <image> <amount of clicks>

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick, click-counting

I've got a clickcounter onclick effect for my webpage, and when I click it, a text that says

You have clicked the button - ??? - times (??? would be the amount of clicks)

The onclick effect works great, but I was wondering if It's possible to change the display of the result. You see, I would like it to instead of having "You have clicked the button", have a miniature version of the picture, so it's like

miniature_image - ???

If that's at all understandable.

This is my current script for my button

**Javascript**

```
function clickCounter(){
     var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
     audio.play();
     if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
         if (localStorage.clickcount)
         {
             localStorage.clickcount=Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
         }
         else
         {
             localStorage.clickcount=1;
         }
         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<center><b>You have clicked the poop
         </b>"+ localStorage.clickcount + "<b> times!</b></center>";
     }
     else{
         document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="I'm sorry to inform you that your browser
         does not support this web storage... I guess you could say that your browser is...
         shit! awwww yeaahh!";
     }
     cursor: pointer;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<center>
     <font face="chiller" color="#603913" "font size="300" <align="center"><b>Click the
     poop!</b>
</center>
<center>
    <p><picture onclick="clickCounter()"><picture
     onmouseover="document.getElementById('touch').play()"><img src="poop.png"></button></p>
</center>
<audio id="audio" src="fart-01.wav"></audio>
<audio id="touch" src="sticky goo.wav"></audio>
<div id="result"></div>
```

I've already tried swapping out the "You have clicked the button" part with image source. like this

```
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<center><img src="poopamount">"+ localStorage.clickcount + "</center>";
```

but that just results in the button onclick effect disappearing. I've also tried using document.GetElementById("image"), but that didn't work either (not sure if i set it up correctly though)

How do I add a picture infront of the amount of clicks? I need it to be part of the result, because as you can see from my script, It's centered, and just positioning a picture wouldn't work because the amount of didgits change.

You can check out my webpage on the link on my stackoverflow profile if you think it would help.

Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: Can you give your code as a fiddle or something so that we can try that live

Comment: I'm gonna try to make one now, though the last time I tried putting my scripts into HTML5, it didn't display anything. I'll post link asap

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b6ttzq7z/
I made the mouseover audio effect work, but as for the onclick effects, i couldn't make them work. but this is what I managed. Hope it helps a little bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link to a fiddle that i believe solves your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/62bwav2L/

In your code I see two divs with the same id, which is not allowed - ids must be unique

```
<div id="result"></div>
...
<div id="result"></div>
```

so - changed that:

```
<div id="resultPoopClick"></div>
...
<div id="result"></div>
```

and then you can go ahead and set your innerHTML with the img tag and all (not that that's a particularly elegant way to do this - but it will work)

```
 document.getElementById("resultPoopClick").innerHTML = "<center>" + localStorage.clickcount + " <img src='http://inftek1.dyndns.org/daniel/Poop/poop.png' width='5%'/></center>";
```

Comment: That's perfect! Though I would like to have the picture before the amount of clicks. Could you help me do that real quick? I tried on your fiddle, but the onclick effect disappeared. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Thank you!! :D It works perfectly! :D
feel free to check out the result on my webpage:

http://inftek1.dyndns.org/daniel/Poop/PoopClicker.html

Comment: Outstanding ;)
What I notice though on my big screen the poop is covered by the pipes! It's not neatly centered like it is for a smaller screen size

Comment: Is there any way to fix this problem? :S
it looks fine on my screen, though I haven't really thought of this problem before.

Comment: You could position your result div absolutely and give it a z-index property of let's say 10000 that will put it on top

Comment: could you please check if the same problems are still occuring for you? I think I've fixed the chatmargin, but the button + the counter are most likely still out of place. Thanks! :)

Comment: yeah - still out of place ... also looks like some of your tags are not properly nested and some aren't closed

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue due to the time when the script is triggered.

Here is the fix and its working for me

```
<center>
    <p>
        <picture onclick="clickCounter()">
            <picture onmouseover="document.getElementById('touch').play()">
                <img src="http://inftek1.dyndns.org/daniel/Poop/poop.png">
                </button>
    </p>
</center>
<audio id="audio" src="http://inftek1.dyndns.org/daniel/Poop/fart-01.wav"></audio>
<div id="result"></div>
<audio id="touch" src="http://inftek1.dyndns.org/daniel/Poop/sticky goo.wav"></audio>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
    function clickCounter() {
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
        audio.play();
        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
            if (localStorage.clickcount) {
                localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) + 1;
            } else {
                localStorage.clickcount = 1;
            }
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<center>" + localStorage.clickcount + "</center>";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Your browser does not support the contents of this webpage";
        }
        //cursor: pointer;
    }
</script>
```

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/b6ttzq7z/2/

Comment: Hey, that works great! :D Does anyone know how to adress my issue though? I could also perhaps align the amount of clicks to that it only expands towards the right (not centered), but then I'd need to manually allign the text to where I want it. Does anyone know how I could do that?